# Setting up Composer path environment variable in Windows 10 home

Tags: php, windows, environment-variables

I've installed Composer PHP dependency manager at Windows 10 home via GUI installer and I desire to set a value for this in the Path environment variable.

From the install it seemed I should go to `C:Users\Username\Appdata\`, isolate further path from there and then put it as a Path value;
but for some reason, I don't find anything that has to with composer in `C:Users\Username\Appdata`.

The search box doesn't give details for any folder named *Composer* even though installing went fine.

How to find the path value for Composer in Windows 10 home?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By searching *composer.bat* at the Windows 10 box (that have dissapointed me with some existing files it didn't found) I eventually found the file at `C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin`.

Comment: After install, there was no C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin folder, but I did find this: C:\Users\myself\AppData\Local\ComposerSetup\bin, which does contain files composer, composer.bat, and composer.phar. This was also added to PATH during install, however I still get `Could not open input file: composer.phar` when running `php composer.phar install` from the website docroot (which has the composer.json and .lock files), and yes PHP is installed correctly and runs fine otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

When I first installed composer on W10 it didn't work at all. I thought it was something to do with php installation on another machine (it was fixed by replacing extension_dir="d:\PHP56\ext" with extension_dir="\\server_name\PHP56\ext"), but I found that installer adds path variable for composer only for the user the installer was run under, not others. As I work under "normal" account and install things under elevated one, my normal did not work. So I copied path env from admin account to normal (Start->Control Panel->User Accounts->Change my environment variables then select path, Edit, Edit text...) and now composer works as expected. I had not such a problem on W7 though.